# Reset corrupted NVRAM on Samsung NP530U3C

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, bootable-media, efi

**Problem:** NVRAM is corrupted and that throws ACPI error which prevents any modern Windows or Windows PE from booting with BSOD. It seems that it is right as described [HERE](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/samsung-series-7-np700z5c-s03ca-my-last-hope.762595/#post-9793018) + ACPI BSOD error.

**What I need to do:** Clear NVRAM in some way or Update BIOS which also clears NVRAM. It is possible to launch the bios update exe in Windows, System uses Phoenix bios and have no options to update firmware within bios.

**What I can do/have done:**

- Get into BIOS and change settings there(UEFI+CSM on, Secureboot off, fast boot off, everything else as default)
- See that Boot list in BIOS contains no values at all.
- Have seen that the only value efibootmgr in Linux finds is Windows boot manager(afraid to delete it as this most likely will brick the laptop entirely)
- Have masked reFind boot manager as Windows boot manager by modifying EFI partition on the hard drive that contains Windows. So the system launches Refind boot manager and I can launch uefi based Linux systems, memtest and some other dos tools that are within uefi based rescue media(have not found dos shell within those tools).

**What I cannot do:**

- Use any Fx keys on startup
- Boot any windows, windows pe or windows re
- Boot any dos
- Find a way to disable ACPI checks on windows startup

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 20.05.2021:**
Can boot into EFI shell, but cannot launch exe files there to update bios.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was 1 of 3 thinks that helped to boot into Windows without BSOD:

1. Disabled AHCI (most likely)
2. Load setup defaults in bios(less likely as it was done before)
3. Disabled internal LAN (less likely)

Do not know the connection between the AHCI and ACPI bios error but maybe it somehow disabled the 24gb internal SSD what comes integrated within these models.